# Vendoring Python packages within another package

Tags: python, pip, package

I have two projects, one of which is a dependency of the other. Because they are private projects, they are not published to PyPI and downloadable through `pip` like normal, but vendored into other projects as needed. My packages are laid out like so:

```
project_a/
  ...
  setup.py

project_b/
  ...
  setup.py
  vendor/
    project_a-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

The `setup.py` file in `project_b` references `project_a` as a normal dependency in `install_requires`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    install_requires=[
        'project_a',
    ],
    # ...
)
```

However, when I try to `pip install project_b` in another project, `project_a` cannot be resolved:

```
Collecting project_a (from project_b==0.0.1)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement project_a (from project_b==0.0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for project_a (from project_b==0.0.1)
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible, or is the correct approach to vendor both `project_a` and `project_b` separately within my other projects?

Comment: Why not set up a local pip proxy and publish to that?

Comment: Also, dependencies can be set up as version-control repository URLs.

Comment: But if you are going to vendor your projects, you would *not* add them as dependecies in the `setup.py` file, because they are *already there in the distribution*.

Comment: See https://github.com/requests/requests and https://github.com/pypa/setuptools for projects that include vendored dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Martjin—using repo URLs doesn't work for me as the repos are private and non-contactable from Heroku (where the users of these packages will end up). Similarly, the local `pip` proxy isn't a good fit for the same reason.

Comment: I will take a look at those links, thanks!